# Hide / Display div based on checkbox click. Works in jsFiddle, but won't on my site. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hide / Display div based on checkbox click. Works in jsFiddle, but won't on my site. Any ideas?

What I'm looking to do is have multiple payment methods (CC, Paypal, etc, etc.) and based on the one you've checked, I'll display the relevant payment information for that method.

Here is the relevant jsFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/mxRCz/88/

My JS is:

```
$('#CCMethod').change(function(){
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#CCPay').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    $('#CCPay').fadeOut('slow');
  }                   
});
```

My site staging area is at: https://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com:444/checkout.aspx

Comment: You have a error on your site from this line `$("#mainslider2").carouFredSel({` and I cannot find the element `#mainslider2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your script

```
  $('#CCMethod').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#CCPay').fadeIn('slow');
      } else {
        $('#CCPay').fadeOut('slow');
      }                   
    });
```

is running before `#CCMethod` is declared.  Wrap it in a doc-ready:

```
$(function() {
    ('#CCMethod').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#CCPay').fadeIn('slow');
      } else {
        $('#CCPay').fadeOut('slow');
      }                   
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use `click` event instead of change, `change` is buggy in old IE (jQuery probably handles this bug, but it's kinda good practice anyway). So try if `click` works for you.

If you don't care about IE<9, take a look at `:checked` pseudoselector. This option doesn't require javascript. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9cQD/ (show/hide animation could be added via `transition`)

P.S. just noticed answer from J Torres - could be the cause.

Answer (score -1):

Change the line:

```
if (this.checked) {
```

for this:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

To check if a checkbox is checked, you must use the '[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)' jQuery selector.

Comment: this.checked is valid and better imo

Comment: Hmm, just tried it, and didn't receive any different result. Still doesn't show when I click the checkbox. Must be something else that's on the page, but I'm not sure what :( Chrome's Console isn't reporting any errors to me.

https://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com:444/checkout.aspx

Comment: Only to confirm, did you add the code into $(document).ready function?