# I am trying to display a div on click of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to display an image and some info about the item when a checkbox is clicked. For some reason nothing is happening and I have been tweaking this for a while with no response whatsoever. 
Here is my javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function displayOnChecked(var checkboxID, var id) {
        if(document.getElementById(checkboxID)) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the stylesheet I have it on `display: none;`

Here is one of my invocations:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="purchasedItem" id = "item" onclick="displayOnChecked('item', 'itemInfo');">
```

Comment: Hit f12 and look at the console in your browser of choice. Do you see any errors? (hint you should see something to the effect of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var` because you are defining your function wrong remove the var.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide / Display div based on checkbox click. Works in jsFiddle, but won't on my site. Any ideas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835271/hide-display-div-based-on-checkbox-click-works-in-jsfiddle-but-wont-on-my-s)

Comment: Why are you passing `item` to the function and then checking for its existence when the checkbox itself is `id=item`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript Hide/show div on checkbox: checked/unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734907/javascript-hide-show-div-on-checkbox-checked-unchecked)

Comment: Y don't you people use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=display+a+div+on+click+of+a+checkbox+JavaScript&btnK=Google+Search)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the `var` keyword in the arguments list of `displayOnChecked`, just have the variable names alone.

If you look in your console, you should be getting an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`

Comment: Omg! Thank you! Such a dumb little mistake.

Comment: @GriffinObeid, if this fixed it, you may check this as the correct answer for further reading

Comment: It is not an answer but rather a comment. There is still an issue. The author checks existence of the checkbox not that the checkbook is checked. @AliKhanusiya provides a possible fix of that

Answer (score 0):

You don't intialize variables as function arguments:

```
function displayOnChecked(var checkboxID, var id)
```

should be

```
unction displayOnChecked(checkboxID, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, just using the CSS *pseudo-element* `:checked`:

```css
.checkmeout {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
left: 150px;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
padding: 12px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.checkmeout img {
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

.checkme:checked ~ .checkmeout {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkme" class="checkme" /> Check Me

<div class="checkmeout">
<img src="" alt="Check Me Out Image" />
<p>Check Me Out Text Description</p>
</div>
</form>
```